# How to save Multiple files into single zip using asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to save Multiple files into single zip using asp.net web form, actually I am download files from Gridview button base on Registration Id into zip. And I am not able to add two or more files into zip. One file is downloading correctly, when I will add second file to zip not getting any logic.

Single file download correctly.

```
zip.AddFile(LatterAcceptance,"My folder");
```

when I will add one more file into zip

```
zip.AddFile((LatterAcceptance,HighestDegree),"My folder");
```

However, If I add another file into zip like `HighestDegree` getting the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Below is my c# code.

```
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    LinkButton Type = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow grow = (GridViewRow)Type.NamingContainer;
    string RegistrationId = gv_TotalAllReg.DataKeys[grow.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();

    bo.Para1 = RegistrationId;//RegId;
    bo.Para2 = "3";//Paravalue
    dt = bl.Admin_Get_UserInformation(bo);

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
        string LA = row["LatterAcceptance"].ToString();
        string LatterAcceptance = Server.MapPath("~/LatterAcceptance/" + LA);

        string HD = row["HighestDegree"].ToString();
        string HighestDegree = Server.MapPath("~/HighestDegree/" + HD);


        zip.AddFile(LatterAcceptance,"My folder");
   }

    Response.Clear();
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;fileName=" + zipName);
    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.End();
```

Comment: What ZipFile type is that? The one from System.IO.Compression does not have an Add() method.

Comment: Any logic to resolve this issue. @Crowcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the DotNetZip library. It may help to read the [documentation](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

You will find the following:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
     // add the report into a different directory in the archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
     zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }
```

You need to do `zip.AddFile()` for each individual file you wish to add to the ZIP.

Comment: Actually you provide two different examples. This "zip.AddFile((LatterAcceptance,HighestDegree),"My folder");
" appears to be incorrect. Whereas in your code you have it in a for-each loop so you are doing the files one at a time. try adding the using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())

Comment: Thank you very much. @Morgan